# What is the utility of converting source code to Java bytecode

Tags: java, jvm, bytecode

Since one needs different JVMs for different architectures, I do not understand the point of compiling to bytecodes. In many other languages, we use different compilers for each target platform (instruction set architure and operating system), but in Java we replace the different compilers with different JVMs.

What is the logic behind introducing the concept of a JVM and the extra bytecode compilation step??

Comment: I strongly recommend that you read the architecture  (java,jvm)

Comment: What’s the logic behind different hardware?

Comment: Is there a connection between these postings? http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/345458/108809 is identical with the [first revision of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/43253554/1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea of the JVM is to allow the programmer to distribute a single version of his software (instead of one for each different platform). The installation of the correct JVM is the responsibility of the user.

The Java language offers an abstraction of OS and system functions, which can then be accessed in the same way. The JVM is what converts those abstractions into system specific commands.